Can events be lost when a lambda with a DLQ is triggered by SNS?
I want to process events from an SNS topic using a lambda function and to keep cost down I don't want to have an SQS queue in between.
I also don't want to lose any events e.g. due to throttling so I'm thinking of having a DLQ for discarded events.
Is it true that an event using this setup will either be successfully handled by the lambda or put on the DLQ? Or are there cases when events could be lost e.g. due to high request rates?
This sentence from the documentation seems to support the latter but I'm not sure:

If the function can't keep up with incoming events, events might also be deleted from the queue without being sent to the function.


The SNS reliability FAQ is probably your best hope of an authoritative answer. Also note that there are scenarios where SNS can fail to send a message to a DLQ and emits the DeadLetterErrors metric (see penultimate paragraph here).

According to AWS Support no events will be lost when a DLQ is used:

Yes, when a DLQ is configured, the events will not get deleted incase of high incoming event rates (throttles) for asynchronous invocations but will be sent to DLQ.


For asynchronous invocation, Lambda places the event in an internal queue and returns a success response without additional information.

When a Dead Letter Queue is not configured, the events are discarded from the internal queue if the function can't keep up with incoming events (default behaviour).
When a Dead Letter Queue is configured on the lambda, the events are sent to the DLQ incase of function errors or throttles due to high invocation rate to prevent loss of events.


